# Pagination redirects to first page at P100

Tags: templates, pagination

I have a page where the pagination works fine until you get to the page that would use "P100" at the end. At that point, it redirects back to the first pagination page. Have any of you had this issue before? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Please update your question to include your EE version number.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a potential bug in EE. I would suggest submitting a bug report using the [**EllisLab Bug Tracker**](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs) (you must be logged in to see the page).